# Is there a way to restore cleared Kaspersky reports in Kaspersky 2013 version?

Tags: kaspersky, crystal-reports

I have access to the `report.rpt` and `detected.rpt` files, but it cannot be opened in a crystal report viewer application.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question? How to open a report in crystal reports, or how to 'unclear' them?

Comment: any one of the two options will help me...

Comment: Do you get any error message when trying to open the report?

Answer (score 1):

You cant access cleared reports, because data was deleted by yourself